# Data Mapper design pattern and many-to-many relationship

Tags: php, design-patterns, datamapper, domain-model

I've read the following articles about `Domain Model` design pattern and `Data Mapper` design pattern:

- http://phpmaster.com/building-a-domain-model/
- http://phpmaster.com/integrating-the-data-mappers/
- http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Building-an-ORM-in-PHP/
- http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Building-an-ORM-in-PHP/1/

It's pretty easy for `one-to-one` relationship. Can anyone explain to me how could I organize `many-to-many` support?

For example: we have tree tables: `posts`, `images` and `posts_href_images`, where the last table is the table to support `many-to-many` relationship between posts and images.

Answer (score 0):

```
posts:
post_id | post data...
1 | "first"
2 | "second"
3 | "third"
4 | "fourth"

images:
image_id | image_data...
1 | "JPEG...."
2 | "PNG...."
3 | "GIF..."
4 | "BMP..."

posts_href_images:
post_id | image_id
1 | 2
1 | 3
2 | 1
2 | 2
3 | 3
```

Now you have the following pairs: (first, PNG), (first,GIF), (second,JPEG), (second,PNG), (third,GIF) [and you can see that fourth and BMP are not in the list] Now you see how can you represent 0, 1, or multiple connections

Comment: I understand how it looks in the database. In the articles above I've not found any lines which shows how to do it in the code. If I rightly understand, I should some code to the `select` method to assign join. Am I right?

Comment: probably. What data would you like to see in your result? (use my example data)

Comment: Imagine: you have the ID of the post and you need to get all images for this post through the table `post_href_images`.

Comment: SELECT i.* FROM posts_href_images pi, images i WHERE pi.image_id=i.image_id and po.post_id = ID

Comment: I don't think I get your question. Can you put up some "example" of what have you tried?